# how to get output file path with shutil.copy

Tags: python-2.7, temporary-files, shutil

```
import tempfile
import shutil

temp_ =  tempfile.mkdtemp()
class ListView_(Screen):
    def Image_(self, path):
        global image_file_path
        file_path = shutil.copy2(path[0], temp_)
```

in python 3
file_path output is a "path"

in python 2 
file_path output is "None"
so how to get the path of the new file in temp directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shutil` comes with source, so you can look into python 3 version and adapt it.

If you compare `shutil.copy2` methods for Python 2.7 & 3.4, you'll notice a new `return dst` in the 3.4 version. That's a new feature added, not present in python 2.

the interesting lines for you in `shutil.copy2` method are:

```
if os.path.isdir(dst):
    dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
```

It means that if `temp_` is a directory, then target is the directory / basename of the source, else leave it as is, so after this code, `dst` is always a target file name, and `open(dst,"wb')` will work.

so to make your code compatible with python 2 & 3 (which is a good thing when it's possible), you can emulate that by using a ternary expression to compute the actual filepath target, then use it directly in `shutil` (why passing a directory again ?):

```
file_path = os.path.join(_temp, os.path.basename(src)) if os.path.isdir(temp_) else temp_
shutil.copy2(path[0], file_path)  # ignore return code
```